# How to clean the queue from all of the processed items?

Tags: c#, multithreading

There is a global queue of objects that you have to send to your customers. Queue is continually filled with new elements in its flow (one element in a second), that`s why you have to send constantly. Every client is served in a separate thread. After the object is sent to all clients it must be removed from the queue. It seems to be easy, but how to know that all the threads have already sent a particular object?

I do everything on the socket.

```
Thread threadForClientSending = new Thread(delegate()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                List<SymbolsTable> [] localArrayList ;

                //main.que -- global queue
                foreach (var eachlist in localArrayList = main.que.ToArray())
                {
                    foreach (var item in eachlist)
                    {
                        byte[] message =
                            encoding.GetBytes((item.GetHashCode()%100).ToString() + " "+item.SDate +"\n\r");

                        client.Send(message);
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Such code sends everything to everyone, but it doesn`t clean the queue.
How to clean the queue from all of the processed items?

```
public static ConcurrentQueue<List<SymbolsTable>> que = new ConcurrentQueue<List<SymbolsTable>>();

public partial class SymbolsTable
    {       
        public string SName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> SPrice { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SVolume { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime SDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Depends entirely on what kind of animal `main.que` is.

Comment: @HenkHolterman
public static ConcurrentQueue<List<SymbolsTable>> que = new ConcurrentQueue<List<SymbolsTable>>();

    public partial class SymbolsTable
    {       
        public string SName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> SPrice { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SVolume { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime SDate { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Update your original question, this way it will be much more readable.

Comment: Yes, don't add code in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE: I highly recommend to define local queue for each client (task in server) to achieve maximum concurrency and cleaner code.**

You can achieve what you need by using a `CountDownEvent` which would hold thread access for each item, We should set it to number of available worker that send data to clients.

here is how we can do it:

**Definitions:**

```
    public static ConcurrentQueue<List<SymbolsTable>> que = new ConcurrentQueue<List<SymbolsTable>>();
    public static CountdownEvent counter = new CountdownEvent(NumberOfThreads);
    private const int NumberOfThreads = 3; //for example we have 3 clients here
```

**Thread:**

```
 Thread threadForClientSending = new Thread(delegate()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        List<SymbolsTable> list;
                        var peek = que.TryPeek(out list);
                        if (!peek)
                        {
                            Thread.Sleep(100); //nothing to pull
                            continue;
                        }

                        foreach (var item in list)
                        {
                            main.que -- global queue

                            byte[] message =
                            encoding.GetBytes((item.GetHashCode() % 100).ToString() + " " + item.SDate + "\n\r");

                            client.Send(message);

                            Thread.Sleep(500);
                        }

                        counter.Signal(); //the thread would signal itself as finished, and wait for others to finish the task

                        lock (que)
                        {
                            List<SymbolsTable> lastList;
                            if (que.TryPeek(out lastList) && lastList.Equals(list))
                            {
                                //just one of the threads would dequeue the item
                                que.TryDequeue(out lastList);

                                counter.Reset(); //reset counter for next iteration
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
```

here we used `TryPeek` to just access the item in queue so we won't remove it, at the end in:

```
                 lock (que)
                    {
                        List<SymbolsTable> lastList;
                        if (que.TryPeek(out lastList) && lastList.Equals(list))
                        {
                            //just one of the threads would dequeue the item
                            que.TryDequeue(out lastList);

                            counter.Reset(); //reset counter for next iteration
                        }
                    }
```

we would lock the `que` so only one thread at a time can access it, then we check to see if the processed item has been removed from queue and if not we will remove it here.

---

**More Elegant Solution (in my Humble Opinion):**

as you saw in previous solution we're blocking threads to finish the task for each item together,adding a local queue to each thread would remove this blocking mechanism, so we can achieve maximum concurrency.

I suggest something like:

```
class GlobalQueue
{
    private readonly List<IMyTask> _subscribers=new List<IMyTask>();

    public void Subscribe(IMyTask task)
    {
        _subscribers.Add(task);
    }

    public void Unsubscribe(IMyTask task)
    {
        _subscribers.Remove(task);
    }

    public void Enqueue(List<SymbolsTable> table)
    {
        foreach (var s in _subscribers)
            s.Enqueue(table);
    }
}

interface IMyTask
{
    void Enqueue(List<SymbolsTable> table);
}
```

which your task would be roughly like:

```
class MyTask : IMyTask
{
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<List<SymbolsTable>> _localQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<List<SymbolsTable>>();
    private readonly Thread _thread;
    private bool _started;

    public void Enqueue(List<SymbolsTable> table)
    {
        _localQueue.Enqueue(table);
    }

    public MyTask()
    {
        _thread = new Thread(Execute);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _started = true;
        _thread.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _started = false;
    }

    private void Execute()
    {
        while (_started)
        {
            try
            {
                List<SymbolsTable> list;
                var peek = _localQueue.TryDequeue(out list);
                if (!peek)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100); //nothing to pull
                    continue;
                }

                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    byte[] message =
                    encoding.GetBytes((item.GetHashCode() % 100).ToString() + " " + item.SDate + "\n\r");

                    client.Send(message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```